# Android Sync-provider - how to generate authToken?

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

These days I am learing `Sync` function of Android. In the `SampleSyncAdapter` code I have found `authToken` but I am not sure how to generate the `authToken`. Do I need to generate this `authToken` in the server side and pass as `json`? If yes which `library` should be used to generate `authToken`?